# ArcGIS Java SDK

Tags: web-service, license, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I am going to develop a  web application based on the requirements below:

1. Loading a three different base image tiff, anything
2. Loading the shapefile for that image.
3. On entering the ID of a polygon, it should get zoomed.
4. On clicking it it should display the information image data

At present I am ArcGIS 10.2 licence key. My questions are what should i take technology, sample. How can I get the client ID for it should I pay for it (I am having desktop licence with me?